# Passing variables with different models between razor pages using MVC.

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is the view to which the controller ActionResult points at :

```
@model MyDTO
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RecoveryHome";
    Layout = "~/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
<script>
    var postPath = '@Url.Action("Upload", "Onsite")';
    var pageData =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
</script>
```

where `MyDTO` is for pageData and in the _AdminLayout ,

```
@model MyOtherDTO
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">       
        var InitData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))         
    </script>
```

`MyOtherDTO` is for InitData.

But this returns with an exception : `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyDTO', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyOtherDTO'.`

One variable is like used for the header part and rest for the remaining part of the page and so will have different models. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: A view cannot have 2 models. Remove the model definition from the Layout page. If you want to display data from `MyOtherDTO` in all pages, use `@Html.Action()` to call a `ChildActionOnly` method that returns a partial view

Comment: @Gera , i want to be able to pass those variables which have different models and here , InitData is present for all the admin pages and pageData will be different for different pages. Sorry if i am still unclear.

Answer (score 3):

You can only pass one `viewmodel` to a view, but that doesn't mean you can only pass one 'DTO'.

It's good practice not to mix up what a viewmodel and a dto are.

```
public class MyViewData
{
    public MyDTO PageData { get; set; }
    public MyOtherDTO InitData { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
@model MyViewData
var pageData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PageData))
```

and

```
@model MyViewData
var InitData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.InitData))
```

Edit: You may find this easier to manage if you use a base class for the layout, eg:

```
public abstract class AdminViewModel
{
    public MyOtherDTO InitData { get; set; }
}

public class PageViewModel : AdminViewModel
{
    public MyDTO PageData { get; set; }
}
```

then you can reuse the AdminViewModel across your admin pages as long as you remember to set the `InitData` in the action.